# How do I get list content to display across multiple columns?

Tags: ee3, bootstrap, content

I am running EE 3.5.7 and Bootstrap 4. I have list content that I would like to display evenly across multiple columns. In EE2 there was a very useful add-on: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/splitter, however I have not been able to find anything that is compatible with EE 3+. Does anyone have any recommended solutions for this kind of challenge?

Comment: Hrmm. This is a tough one, and one of the few problems I've allowed myself to turn on PHP in a template, and it looks real ugly in the template. There is no native way to do this without an add-on or turning on PHP for that template. If the add-on is abandoned, as it appears to be, I don't see any problem with taking it and upgrading it yourself. It's a plugin, and those are the easiest and quickest to upgrade and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use css instead of bootsrap... You can use the `column` feature of css. There's many option/parameters..

Look here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns
or here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Thank you.